# Await for a list of tasks, one at a time

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following code, and I'm not sure if it's going to run the tasks one at the time, or run all of them at the same time, and await for all of them to finish.

```
    Dictionary<TemporaryAdditionalData, Exception> rejected = new Dictionary<TemporaryAdditionalData, Exception>();

    await Task.WhenAll(additionalData
        .SelectMaybe(async adda => 
            await this.InsertTemporallyAdditionalData(
                guid, adda.Order, adda.ID, adda.Value, adda.IsMandatory
            ), 
            out rejected
        ).ToArray()
    );

    return rejected;
```

I think the `SelectMaybe` method is not relevant here, it's just an extension to LINQ's `Select` that automatically catches exceptions and returns them.

1) The tasks will run one by one or all at the same time?

2) Whatever is the answer to 1, how could I write the same code to do the opposite?

Comment: Run the code and find out for yourself which it's doing.  It's a simple enough test.

Comment: @Servy I'll try, i might have to come up with a more simple version of the same logic, as i don't have the resources right now to test that specific implementation.

Comment: That would be the best way to test that behavior, yes.

Comment: the opposite way = first run call all methods and store them as task second run await all tasks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tasks will be executed in parallel. If you would like them to execute sequentially, you can write a simple loop like this:

```
foreach (var adda in additionalData) 
{        
    try 
    {
       await this.InsertTemporallyAdditionalData(
           guid, adda.Order, adda.ID, adda.Value, adda.IsMandatory
       );
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
         rejected[adda] = ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. For some reason they still get executed in parallalel – as can be confirmed by EF blowing up with "A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed" due to its single async operation per thread limitation. Any ideas?